# Можно ли не указывать header Content-Type?

Tags: php, header

Можно ли не указывать header Content-Type? Одним php файлом отдаю разные типы - txt, rar, ppt, вот и возник этот вопрос.

Comment: Не указывать - можно. Но что из этого получится - другой вопрос... Вообще, лучше всегда стараться не перенапрягаться и считать, что всю [секцию 14 RFC 2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14) придумали только для того, чтобы программистов хоть чем-нибудь занять :-)

Comment: смотря что вы делаете после с этим файлом.

Comment: @Ninazu на загрузку естественно

Comment: @PinkTux , как насчёт application/x-force-download?

Comment: @Rammsteinik, и как это отдать без Content-Type?

Comment: @PinkTux это и есть Content-Type

Comment: @Rammsteinik,  я внимательно перечитал вопрос. В нём спрашивается "можно ли не указывать Content-Type". Можно. Но тогда и никакого `application/x-force-download` быть не может, так как это *зачение* заголовка с именем *Content-Type*.

Comment: @PinkTux имелось ввиду, что если лучше указывать, то force-download как общий заголовок может подойти?

Comment: Как общий - может, но почему бы не указать реальный, который соответствует контенту?

Comment: @PinkTux лень )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идёт от отдаче какого-то контента для сохранения в виде файла, имеет смысл придерживаться примерно такой схемы:

1. Обязательные заголовки:

   `Content-Type: НУЖНЫЙ_ТИП
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=ИМЯ_ФАЙЛА
    Content-Length: РАЗМЕР_ФАЙЛА
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary`
2. Необязательные (отключение кэширования и т.д.):

   `Expires: 0
    Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
   ...`
3. Если же речь идёт об отдаче большого файла с возможностью докачки, или многопотоковой выкачки, то это уже совсем другая история...

Answer (score 0):

В [HTTP спецификации указано](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-124), что для определения типа содержимого, вы должны отдать заголовок `Content-Type`. Там есть [пояснение](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-7.2.1) по поводу отсутствия этого заголовка.

> Any HTTP/1.1 message containing an entity-body SHOULD include a
> Content-Type header field defining the media type of that body. If
> and only if the media type is not given by a Content-Type field, the
> recipient MAY attempt to guess the media type via inspection of its
> content and/or the name extension(s) of the URI used to identify the
> resource. If the media type remains unknown, the recipient SHOULD
> treat it as type "application/octet-stream".

Клиент может угадать тип содержимого по содержанию файла или по URI. Но это более затратно.

От себя скажу, что это плохая практика не отдавать этот заголовок, т.к. проксирующие сервера или сервера промежуточной обработки могут вести себя некорректно, что приносит администраторам и программистам много головной боли. Как пример: кэширование картинок через `nginx`(просто отдает ошибку `415 unsupported media type`).